# getattr with django models, where db_column is in use

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have django model:

```
class A_Model(model.Models):
     a_Column=models.IntegerField(default=0,db_column='a Column', verbose_name='a Column'),
```

and in views:

```
aObject = A_Model.objects.filter(pk=1)
x = getattr(aObject, 'a Column')
```

I've thought it should work, but it get `exception [...] "object has no attribute 'a Column'"`

Anybody know what is the reason and know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Whatever the value of the db column, the attribute on the model is still called `a_Column`; why would you not use that?

Comment: let's say I need to access model attribute by variable that contains space, which is illegal for attribute name. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes but a) how would you even have that attribute in the first place and b) that is not at all what is going on here, the attribute is still a_Column.